# Link in jQuery mobile collapsible not renderd as button only link is showing up

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-collapsible

My html

```
<form>
    <input data-type="search" id="searchForCollapsibleSet">
</form>
    <div data-role="collapsibleset" data-filter="true" data-inset="true" id="collapsiblesetForFilter" data-input="#searchForCollapsibleSet">
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-filtertext="Resources">
            <h3>Resources</h3>
            <ul id="rsscontent" data-role="listview" data-inset="false">              
                <li><a href="http://www.google.com/">Google.com</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
  </div>
```

Google.com got rendered fine as button.

Using some JS like:

```
var dataline = '<li><a href="http://www.google.com/">Google.com</a></li>';
$('#rsscontent').append(dataline);
```

Google.com got renderd only as link not as button.

Do I need to trigger an event to rerender the page?

http://jsfiddle.net/4dhwK/

Comment: `$('#rsscontent').append(dataline).listview("refresh");` http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/4dhwK/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#rsscontent').append(dataline).listview("refresh");
```